# How does str.replace work?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a conceptual question. I was trying to get rid of the punctuations in a string, so I wrote the following function:

```
def nopunc(str):
    for x in string.punctuation:
        str = str.replace(x, " ")
    return str
```

This worked. However, when I changed the function a little bit:

```
def nopunc(str):
    for x in string.punctuation:
        str1 = str.replace(x, " ")
    return str1
```

it didn't work. Instead of having `str = str.replace(x, "")`, I gave the string a new name called `str1`. Why would that cause a problem? Does it have something to do with `.replace`?

Comment: Well think about it - when you loop around to the second `x`, what is `str`? (Also, don't use `str` as your own variable name.)

Comment: An aside:  Don't name your variable `str` as this shadows Python's `str` and is likely to confuse readers of your code.

Comment: Your confusion is not really about the nature of `replace`.  Rather, it's about of the nature of assigment in Python.  Read Ned Batchelder's [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) and you will understand Python much better.

Comment: Alternatively, how about this: `re.sub('[%s]' % string.punctuation, ' ', s)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because strings are immutable, `str.replace(x, " ")` does **not** modify the string object referenced by `str` in any way.  Instead, it returns a *copy* of this object were `x` is replaced with `" "`.

In your first for-loop, every iteration assigns this newly created object to the existing name `str`.  So, your first function is basically equivalent to:

```
def nopunc(str):
    str = str.replace(string.punctuation[0], " ")
    str = str.replace(string.punctuation[1], " ")
    str = str.replace(string.punctuation[2], " ")
    ...
    str = str.replace(string.punctuation[31], " ")
    return str
```

Notice how the value of the name `str` is continually updated, thereby saving any changes.

The second for-loop however just repeatedly reassigns the name `str1` to `str.replace(x, " ")`.  This means that your second function is no different than doing:

```
def nopunc(str):
    str1 = str.replace(string.punctuation[31], " ")
    return str1
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace does not change the value held by `str`. It is your `=` assignment that does.

In the first case, all replacements add up, because each call with a different punctuation mark replaces stuff in the string resulting from the previous replacement.

In the second case, all replacements are lost because each call with a new punctuation mark replaces stuff in the (unchanging) original string, and only returns the last replacement (which is replacing tildes with spaces).